# inverse laplace of sine function

Tags: laplace-transform

I use the transformation rule
$L(f(t)*t^n) = F^{(n)}(s)(-1)^n$
to find out the inverse Laplace of $\sin(s)$.

$F(s) = \sin(s)$

$F''(s)=-F(s)$

$L(f(t)*t^2) = F''(s) = -F(s) = -L(f(t))$

$L(f(t)(1+t^2))= 0$

Here I can only see the trivial solution $f(t) = 0$. Is there any function whose Laplace is zero, other than zero? I mean I wonder where is my error?

Comment: 1) The answer in the reference given by @alexjo isn't an answer (Post formula is a deadend, at least in this case) 2) If this LT exist has a meaning, it cannot be a "pure" function because of the initial value theorem (see http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceXform/FwdLaplace/LaplaceProps.html). It must at least involve $\delta$s... 3) Why do you need such an inverse Laplace Transform ?

Comment: I don't need it, just curiosity.

Comment: One nontrivial thing to consider is whether such an $f$ need even exist.

Answer (score 0):

OK I got it. Whenever we take a derivative of something we must lose some information. Here the rule is a specific part of the general thing.

If we say

$L(tf(t))=-F'(s)$

then the most general form of F(s) is

$F(s)=L(f(t))+C$

for arbitrary C. Thus, considering the previous equation

$L(t^2f(t))=F''(s)$

$F(s)=L(f(t))+as+b$

$F''(s)=-F(s)=L(t^2f(t))=-L(f(t))-as-b$

$L(f(t)(t^2+1))=-(as+b)$

$f(t)=[L^{-1}(as+b)]/(t^2+1)$

I've ignored the minus sign due to arbitrary a and b.

$f(t)=[aL^{-1}(s) + L^{-1}(b)]/(t^2+1)$

$f(t)=a\delta'(t)/(t^2+1) + b\delta(t)/(t^2+1)$

a,b are arbitrary values. Since our differential equation has 2 degrees of ambiguity it seems convenient to have it in solution, too.
I think one of them is for sine and the other is for cosine.

Comment: Are you sure? what is the Laplace transform of $f(t)=a\delta'(t)/(t^2+1) + b\delta(t)/(t^2+1)$?

Comment: I'm sure I sucked up, it's easy to see that this method doesn't work by looking other similar examples like F(s)=F'(s). But it's so annoying when you can't find out the mistake you've made.

Answer (score 0):

If $\mathcal L\{f\} = F(s)$ vanishes on an infinite sequence of points that are
located at equal intervals along a line parallel to the real axis
$$
 F(s_0+n\sigma)=0\qquad (\sigma >0, n=1,\,2,\,\ldots)
$$
$s_0$ being a point of convergence of $\mathcal L\{f\}$; then it follows that $f(t)$ is a nullfunction.

So it follows that a Laplace transform $F(s)\neq 0$ cannot be periodic.

> **Thus $\sin(s)$ cannot be the Laplace transform of a function.**

Comment: OK, but what if we consider only one cycle?